# Create message prompt in Firebird trigger

Tags: triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

Is it possible in a trigger to prompt the user with an error message?

For example, if the user hadn't entered a value in a field, then it prompts them and doesn't save the record.

I don't know if error message is the correct term. It may be exception.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Firebird's version is at least 2.5, the short answer is - yes.

You just create a simple exception like this

```
create exception my_universal_exception 'This is the default exception text';
```

Then use it in your trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER A0 ACTIVE
BEFORE insert POSITION 0
as
begin
  if (new.id is null)
    then exception my_universal_exception 'You should specify some value for ID.';
end
```

Personally I'm using a bit more complex approach. I have a dedicated procedure that takes a text argument and by default raises an exception however depending on other user variables writes the exception to a logging table or does any other useful things:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SHOW_ERROR (
    ERROR_TEXT varchar(256) )
AS
begin
  if ((select rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'SILENT_MODE') from rdb$database) is not null)
    then insert into s_log(log_message)values(:error_text);
    else exception my_universal_exception :error_text;
end
```

Thus later I use it in my triggers like this:

```
  if (new.id is null)
    then execute procedure show_error('You should specify some value for ID.');
```

Also please note, that starting from Firebird 3.0 you can also use parameters in your exceptions [as described here](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-exceptparams.html).

And of course, your client software should handle such kind of error accordingly but this is way out of scope for this question.